# diferenciar letras maiúsculas de minúsculas

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estou realizando consulta banco, mas gostaria que fosse diferenciado as letras maiúsculas de minúsculas, porque da forma como está se eu digitar **teste** e valor que está no banco for **Teste** não recebo nada em minha consulta, alguma forma de fazer isso com `Linq`?

Meu `controler`

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pagina, string consulta)
{
    int paginaTamanho = 10;
    int paginaNumero = (pagina ?? 1);
    var dados = db.Ramais.ToList();
    return View(dados.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho));
}
```

Comment: Qual é o seu banco de dados e qual versão do entity framework é o seu projeto?

Answer (score 1):

já tentou usar isso aqui ?

```
suaString.ToUpper());
```

Ou se preferir da pra ignorar maiúsculas de minúsculas

ex: `var texto.Equals("Minha string",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`